# Latest remix version is not detecting metamask

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, remix, metamask

I just updated Remix to the latest version and it is not detecting metamask wallet when I try to select Injected Web3 from the list of environments.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is working on my end right now, but I had similar issues in the past and I was unblocked by using their alpha version : https://remix-alpha.ethereum.org/ . Maybe that can help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cookies of your browser and then start remix. before that backup your all files of remix. Maybe this could help